# I want to set a command, so that when I use itemize in the end of every item to be a specific symbol (automatically)

Tags: itemize

I want to set a command, so that when I use itemize in the end of every item to be a specific symbol (automatically). For example, `\Rightarrow`. My purpose is to create proofs with itemize and the basic "step separator" want to be the `\Rightarrow`. (I know that I can write in the end of every item the `$\Rightarrow$`).

Comment: including the last item?

Comment: No. This is useful remark

Comment: So tell me and the two cases

Comment: simplest is just to do `\newcommand\myindex[1]{\index #1 $\Rightarrow$}` but the details are tricky, might the text end with a nested list or with display math, where do you want the arrow to go?

Comment: Do you just need this in the `itemize` environment, or might you need it on others as well (e.g. `enumerate`)?

Comment: It is good to know  it and for enumerate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Did you mean `\item`?  Or is there some cleverness that you're using that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I meant \myitem rather than \myindex but it's only a name

Comment: Generally, the end of an \item is beginning of another \item, which is also \par.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a *bad* feeling about this, as it's a bit of a dirty hack. However, it doesn't appear to break anything obvious. The idea is to place an arrow immediately before each instance of `\item`, except the first. I haven't tried this trick with any other environments; use it at your own risk!

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{mylist}
{\begin{enumerate}
\let\olditem\item
\newif\iffirst
\firsttrue
\renewcommand\item{\iffirst\firstfalse\else\(\Rightarrow\)\fi\olditem}}
{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{mylist}
\item The first
\item The second
\item[KK] The third  %Check that optional argument still works
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

If your items don't contain any problematic code like verbatim etc., you could use the same approach as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2006#a2254 with the `getitems` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{getitems}

\makeatletter
\def\doitem#1{\item #1\ifnum\thecurrentitemnumber=\thenumgathereditems\else$\Rightarrow$\fi}%

\makeatother

\let\origitemize\itemize
\let\origenditemize\enditemize

\usepackage{environ}

\RenewEnviron{itemize}{%
  \expandafter\gatheritems\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \gathereditem{0}%
  \origitemize%
   \loopthroughitemswithcommand{\doitem}%
  \origenditemize%
}  


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item The first
\item The second
\item The third 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]